# How to ascertain if a cell/field contains a value in ArcGIS attribute table

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I have done a bit of research on this but can't seem to find an answer. I am wondering if there is a way to identify whether a cell/field in the ArcGIS attribute table contains a value using the search cursor. Initially, I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(node110, "node_layer12")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("node_layer12", "NEW_SELECTION", query1)

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("node_layer12")
for row in rows:
        link_id2 = row.getValue("DRN_link")

if link_id2 == "E*":
    print "YES"
```

unfortunately this didn't work. I knew that if the field I was searching had a value it would start with an 'E' so I thought a wildcard might work. Obviously not. Any ideas?

Please note. I only have access to arcgis 10 so can't use the arcpy.da.searchcursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is currently only checking the last value it gets in `link_id2`. To check *every* value of `link_id2` (and presumably do some operation if it matches the condition) embed the conditional within the loop.

You can use the [python `.startswith()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check for strings starting with the letter "E":

```
for row in rows:
    link_id2 = row.getValue("DRN_link")
    if link_id2.startswith("E"):
        print "YES"
```

If you are checking whether many (dozens or more) rows meet a particular condition, you can instead count them:

```
counter = 0
for row in rows:
    link_id2 = row.getValue("DRN_link")
    if link_id2.startswith("E"):
        counter += 1
print counter
```

Comment: the test is good, but I would store a boolean in the loop then put the print statement out of the loop, otherwise you might print hundreds of YES's

Comment: good point, added an alternative :)

Comment: Thanks Erica, it works. I haven't come across the startswith function before.